# Can Ass Whuppin' be used to target a permanent in your own game?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Ass Whuppin'](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAss%5d%2b%5bWhuppin%27%5d) is a silver-bordered card from the set Unhinged whose card text reads "Destroy target silver-bordered permanent in any game you can see from your seat."  Technically, if me or my opponent have silver-bordered cards in play, I can probably see them from my seat, so can I target them for removal with this spell?  Or does it have to be a silver-bordered permanent from a different game?  I've checked the Unhinged FAQ and Google, and can't find any answers to this scenario.  The FAQ does mention that the target has to be in a silver-bordered game, i.e., a game where at least one player is using a deck that uses at least one silver-bordered card.  But that's about it.  Technically, if I'm using Ass Whuppin', then I'm in a silver-bordered game myself.

Edit:  It's occurred to me I should probably provide the FAQ:  [Unhinged FAQTIWDAWCC](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/unhinged-faqtiwdawcc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can see your own game, and Ass Whuppin' makes no limitation on which game its target has to be in, so you can target cards in your own game. This is necessary to be able to use the card at all in a silver-bordered game when nobody around you is playing another silver-bordered game.

That being said, the whole point of Ass Whuppin', and indeed all Un-sets, is to mess with the rules of the game and have a good laugh about it. If you can mess with other games through Ass Whuppin', but you are looking to powerplay in your own game, you're probably doing it wrong.